# How to make a .NET web site host/open a WebService

Tags: c#, web-services

I am working on a **.NET Web Site** with **Framework 3.5** that someone else created/configured

This project has many **WebServices** inside the **App_Code** folder and when the project is launched many of the **WebServices** are being hosted and the WSDL can be accesed like this

```
http://localhost:23338/Presentation/Services/BillingService.asmx?wsdl
```

I have been asked to add a new WebService that can also be hosted like that, so I have created a **AdminExtractosService** class like this

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class AdminExtractosService : WebService
{
    public AdminExtractosService()
    {
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string SomeMethod(DateTime selectedDate)
    {
        //logic here
    }
```

But that AdminExtractosService is not being hosted,the WSDL is not available under **/Presentation/Services/AdministracionExtractosService.asmx?wsdl**

I have checked the **Web.config** for the website but there is no section for any of the other services that already exist in the App_Code folder,the Solution has a Single Start project which is the Presentacion project so how else are this services being hosted ?

What do i need to do to make my **AdminExtractosService** start when the web site is launched ?

Comment: I have also checked to see if the ServiceHost class is being use to host all the other services but there is no use of that either.

Comment: you add a class file or add a web service file?

Comment: I added a class file that extends a WebService and that is how all the existing services are created. In fact the Class I added has the same ICON in the Solution Explorer as all the others

Comment: You have to create an `.asmx` file that inherits your new class.  Just copy one of the existing ones, and change the class name.

Comment: @MikeChristensen thanks...there were not inside the same folder, and this is a big solution with 14 projects inside. I will try this and let you know. (post it as an answer to give you credits)

Comment: Viewed almost 200 times with an accepted answer and is still downvoted ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file called `AdminExtractosService.asmx` and put the following in it:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="AdminExtractosService.asmx.cs" Class="AdminExtractosService" %>
```

You'll then be able to access your web service at:

```
/AdminExtractosService.asmx
```

Comment: Mike thanks for you help, in my specific case I need to locate the file AdminExtractosService.asmx under the Services folder and it can be accesed under the /Services/AdminExtractosService.asmx